# Configuring UITableView cell text-field keyboard type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikeyboardtype

I'm trying to configure the cells of my table view to have different different keyboard configurations based upon what type of cell is being displayed.

In my `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method, I have the following code to check for the value of the `UILabel.text` on the keyboard appropriately:

```
    if cell.entityLabel.text == "Home" || cell.entityLabel.text == "Mobile" {
        cell.entityTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.namePhonePad
    }
```

However, these cells still display the same "default" keyboard.

Any idea what I may be missing?

EDIT: I had forgotten something important! These `UITableView` cells are actually being created in a separate class, `EditTableViewCell.swift`. So, I modified the `awakeFromNib()` method as shown below (but still getting the same results):

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

```
if entityLabel.text == "Home" || entityLabel.text == "Mobile" {
    entityTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.namePhonePad
    entityTextField.reloadInputViews()
}



else {
    entityTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    entityTextField.reloadInputViews()
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Add else statement to your expression for correct reuse logic, for example:

```
if cell.entityLabel.text == "Home" || cell.entityLabel.text == "Mobile" {
    cell.entityTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.namePhonePad
} else {
    cell.entityTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.emailAddress
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I gave that a shot, but still got the same result as before :/

Comment: What `text` property contains?

Comment: I apologize; I'm not entirely sure what you're asking

Comment: Did you try to add a breakpoint into `if` branch? Why your condition don't work? Check value in `text` property of `cell.entityLabel`

Comment: Ah, yes; I did set break-points, and the logic of changing the keyboard type was being reached correctly.